# Samba Error NT_STATUS_HOST_UNREACHABLE on any other node yet not on host

Tags: filesystems, configuration, samba, file-sharing, smb

host IP config:

```
# netstat -nat | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139                 0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN
```

host smbclient

```
# smbclient //*********/share pwd -U observer
Domain=[MYGROUP] OS=[Unix] Server=[Samba 3.6.23-14.el6_6]
smb: \> ls
  .                                   D        0  Fri Aug  7 19:26:46 2015
  ..                                  D        0  Fri Aug  7 18:57:16 2015
  hello                                        4  Fri Aug  7 19:26:44 2015

                41115 blocks of size 262144. 20549 blocks available
smb: \>
```

any other node

```
#  smbclient //******/share/ pwd -U observer
Connection to ******* failed (Error NT_STATUS_HOST_UNREACHABLE)
```

fails in a manner alike from Windows clients.

host samba folder config (the only thing changed in default one, added to the end):

```
[share]
path = /home/observer/share
available = yes
valid users = observer
read only = yes
browsable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
```

Why can samba clients throw `Error NT_STATUS_HOST_UNREACHABLE` if samba works locally and all ports are open?

Comment: Say OS please (Fedora used to have a default-deny firewall).  I'm not sure you've ruled out name resolution so you should say whether you're using IP address or a hostname.  And you should be able to show the name/address to us - if it's an IPv4 address it will be a private one (NAT).

Comment: Did you checked the  server firewall ports (disable firewall to make tests)? The machines are in the same network? Can you ping the server from the clients?